# asp.net add search for more than one dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, search, drop-down-menu

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-and-Search-ASP.Net-DropDownList-items-using-JavaScript.aspx) in order to search in a dropdownlist. It works fine.

But, when I add another dropdownlist in the same page and use the same strategy for it, only one of them works fine.

What is the right way to add two searches for two dropdownlists?

Here is javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var ddlText, ddlValue, ddl, lblMesg, ddlText1, ddlValue1, ddl1, lblMesg1;
     function CacheItems() {
         ddlText = new Array();
         ddlValue = new Array();
         ddl = document.getElementById("<%=ddlActivities.ClientID %>");
        lblMesg = document.getElementById("<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>");
        for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
            ddlText[ddlText.length] = ddl.options[i].text;
            ddlValue[ddlValue.length] = ddl.options[i].value;
        }

        ddlText1 = new Array();
        ddlValue1 = new Array();
        ddl1 = document.getElementById("<%=ddlParicipent.ClientID %>");
        lblMesg1 = document.getElementById("<%=lblMessageParticipant.ClientID%>");
         for (var i = 0; i < ddl1.options.length; i++) {
             ddlText1[ddlText1.length] = ddl1.options[i].text;
             ddlValue1[ddlValue1.length] = ddl1.options[i].value;
         }
    }
    window.onload = CacheItems;

    function Filter(value) {
        ddl.options.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < ddlText.length; i++) {
            if (ddlText[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1) {
                AddItem(ddlText[i], ddlValue[i]);
            }
        }
        lblMesg.innerHTML = ddl.options.length + " items found.";
        if (ddl.options.length == 0) {
            AddItem("No items found.", "");
        }
    }

    function AddItem(text, value) {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.text = text;
        opt.value = value;
        ddl.options.add(opt);
    }

    function FilterParticipant(value) {
        ddl1.options.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < ddlText1.length; i++) {
            if (ddlText1[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1) {
                AddItem1(ddlText1[i], ddlValue1[i]);
            }
        }
        lblMesg1.innerHTML = ddl1.options.length + " items found.";
        if (ddl1.options.length == 0) {
            AddItem1("No items found.", "");
        }
    }

    function AddItem1(text, value) {
        var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
        opt1.text = text;
        opt1.value = value;
        ddl1.options.add(opt1);
    }
</script>
```

and HTML script:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"
                onkeyup="Filter(this.value)"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActivities" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlActivities" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" OnDataBound="ddlActivities_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div><div class="editor-field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
                    onkeyup="FilterParticipant(this.value)"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParicipent" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sqlParticipent" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" OnDataBound="ddlParicipent_DataBound">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessageParticipant" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing CacheItems functions for all dropdown lists, share you code .

Comment: @Sami I updated my question.

Comment: Looks okay, would you please share Dropdowns HTML ?

Comment: @Sami Sure, please check the question again

Comment: When you say "only one of them works fine", do you mean that one works and the other doesn't?  If so, which one works and which one doesn't?  Or does it alternate?

Comment: @AnnL. Yes, the first one works, but the other doesn't

Comment: I have to say, everything looks OK. Does any part of the 2nd DDL search work?  Do you get either the "# items found" or the "No options found" message?  Have you tried using your browser's JavaScript debugger?

Comment: @AnnL. No, nothing of the 2nd DDL search is working :

Comment: Does `ddlParicipent` actually have any options in it, when you run it? And are "Name" and "ID" the right names for the properties to use for the option description and value?  I'm just wondering if it isn't getting bound on the server side.

Comment: Also, since I'm assuming the javascript is embedded in your web page, you might want to take a look at the "page source" in your browser and see what it looks like, whether any of the embedded `document.getElementById("<%#  something.ClientID %>")` tags are resulting in invalid IDs or bad syntax.

Comment: @AnnL. Well, this might help figuring out the problem. i have the first ddl inside panel1, and the 2nd ddl inside panel2. and each time only one of the panels is visible. But if have both ddls in the same panel, the code works fine. what do you think is the problem?

Comment: @AnnL. I need each ddl in a panel where only one panel is visible at a time

Comment: When you say "visible" I assume you mean that you're setting the ASP.NET Panel control .Visible property to false, rather than hiding it via CSS.

Comment: In that case, when you're showing your second panel, your first panel is not getting rendered to the screen at all.  So the part of the javascript that attempts to deal with them will fail: the controls `ddlActivities` and `lblMessage` won't have ClientIDs (I don't think) and even if they did, the HTML that gets sent down won't include them, so there'd be no elements that have those ClientIDs on the page.

Comment: So `CacheItems` will fail, and since it will fail before it gets to the setup for your second DDL, that part will never get set up.

Comment: @AnnL. I see. So what do you suggest to do?

Comment: I'll put it in answer form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, your problems are likely occurring because when your first panel is hidden, the first `document.getElementById` call in your javascript will return null.

If you then attempt to do something with the result, you'll get an error - and the second dropdown search will never get set up.

There are a couple of ways to approach this, to make it more robust (and to make it something you could use on other pages without having to repeat the code for every dropdown) but the simplest would probably be this:

```
    ddlText = new Array();
    ddlValue = new Array(); 
    ddl = document.getElementById("<%=ddlActivities.ClientID %>");
    lblMesg = document.getElementById("<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>");
    if(ddl != null && lblMesg != null)  // <-- new code
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
           ddlText[ddlText.length] = ddl.options[i].text;
           ddlValue[ddlValue.length] = ddl.options[i].value;
        }
    } 
    ddlText1 = new Array();
    ddlValue1 = new Array();
    ddl1 = document.getElementById("<%=ddlParicipent.ClientID %>");
    lblMesg1 = document.getElementById("<%=lblMessageParticipant.ClientID%>");
    if(ddl1 != null && lblMesg1 != null) // <-- new code
    {
         for (var i = 0; i < ddl1.options.length; i++) {
             ddlText1[ddlText1.length] = ddl1.options[i].text;
             ddlValue1[ddlValue1.length] = ddl1.options[i].value;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much